# Heap-like data structure with fast random access?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dictionary, heap

My situation is the following:

- I have a collection of entities, each of which has a "goodness" property.
- I wish to grab the entities one at a time, from "best" to "worst."
- After a "best" entity is grabbed, the "goodness" properties of several (relatively few) of my other entities change, and this change must be incorporated into my upcoming decision of the next "best" entity to grab.
- Some (relatively few) entities may become "worthless" after a grab, and these should be removed from my collection.
- It is easy for me to construct, given the entity that I just grabbed, the set of now-"dirty" objects, that is, the set of entities which potentially have a now-different "goodness," or have become "worthless."

So, I need a data structure that allows me to:

- Quickly grab the "biggest" of a collection (as in, a max-heap).
- Quickly update the underlying ordering of the objects in my collection to accommodate the situation described above.  (Easy to do in a heap, if we can access the dirty objects' locations, e.g. array indices, within the underlying heap implementation.)
- There is a guarantee that there are no collisions among the entries of my collection.  (The entries are references to the entities I described above.)

The idea I have is to use a max-heap together with an unordered map, keyed on the heap entries, and having values equal to, e.g., the objects' respective indices in the underlying array in the heap implementation.

What I'm wondering is whether there may be a data structure which is better for this situation.

Comment: Define "relartively few" 1/10 of the elements? sqrt(n) of the elements? log(n) of the elements? log(log(n))? .... what's the scale of the elements that are needed to be updated at each iteration?

Comment: The number of the entities that need to be updated after a grab can for our purposes be treated as constant.  The more important thing is that there will be a number of grabs that is roughly linear in the number of original entities.

Comment: Is the update of an item's goodness ever for the better?

Comment: Sorry, that's a good question, I should have addressed that.  Entities only get worse.  Although, it would be a nice thing if whatever solution we come up with does work even if entities are allowed to get better.

Comment: I can't think of a better one.  But even if I could, you can't get more than a constant factor of improvement.  Odds are that this won't be material to your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

If few members are affected when the best entity is grabbed, then you might be able to improve the runtime by using a linked list and an unordered map (each with the original set of entities), and a max heap.  After removing the best entity from the end of the linked list you'll use the map to locate the affected entities, removing them from the list and adding the non-worthless entities to the max heap.  Thereafter, the next best entity is the greater of the entity at the end of the list or the max entity in the heap.  The advantage of this setup is that removal from the linked list is a constant time operation, and insertion into the max heap will be a relatively small (compared to the total number of entities) log time operation.

Because entities' values can only get worse, you can lazily remove them from the linked list - if the item is worthless then remove it, and if its value has changed then flag it as "changed."  Check the "changed" flag on the entity at the end of the linked list, and if it's "true" then remove the entity and add it to the max-heap.  The advantage of lazy updates is that you usually won't need to update items that are in the heap (you'll just need to update the value of items in the linked list), and if an item is changed and then later made worthless then you can remove it from the linked list without ever having to add it to the heap.